# Animated fade in Bootstrap/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this fade-in effect of the pictures when hovering over them with the accompanying button appearing using bootstrap/CSS.

This design agency(http://riotdesign.eu/en/blog/page/2/?_=1398082943473) does it on their blog and it looks really cool. I wasn't able to discern how to do it from looking at the code through inspector. Any guidance on where I can learn about this feature would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Been busy with another project will get on this tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it through css , here is the [JS Fiddle Simple Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/D7MhQ/) and below is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parentDiv" class="myDiv">
    <div class="img" ></div>
    <div id="secondChild">Lorem Ipsum Colro dito pilo Lorem Ipsum Colro dito pilo Lorem Ipsum Colro dito pilo Lorem Ipsum Colro </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myDiv
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:600px;
    height:200px;

}
.myDiv .img{
    position: absolute;
    margin:5px;
    width: 200px;
    height:180px;
    background:url("http://www.ideachampions.com/weblogs/Good-news11.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 200px 180px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    transition:all 2s;

}

.myDiv:hover .img{
    background-size: 300px 360px;
}
#secondChild
{
    position : absolute;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can. Try something like below.

```
.grow {

  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height : 20px;
    width : 50px;
    border : 2px;
}
.grow:hover, .grow:focus, .grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Have a look at **Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/kN2bp/1/ 
Just add a image in div

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, take a look at this code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="img-container">
        <input type="button" value="button" id="btn" />
        <img src="http://www.ideachampions.com/weblogs/Good-news11.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#img-container {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
#img-container img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
}
#img-container:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
#btn {
    opacity:0;
    display:inline;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    z-index:10;
}
#img-container:hover #btn {
    opacity:1;
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/Shn2Y/)**